# How to fix an error in a php variable? Server gives 500 error

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code that is responsible for add money to account. There are tariff plans on the page of the site, when you click pay, the user switches to paying the bill. The code is as follows:

```
   public function pay(Request $request)
    {
        $ticketID = $request->get('tickID');
        if($ticketID = 1){
            $sum = 32;
        }elseif($ticketID = 2){
            $sum = 64;
        }elseif($ticketID = 3){
            $sum = 320;
        }elseif($ticketID = 4){
            $sum = 640;
        }elseif($ticketID = 5){
            $sum = 1600;
        }elseif($ticketID = 6){
            $sum = 3840;
        }elseif($ticketID = 7){
            $sum = 6400;
        }elseif($ticketID = 8){
            $sum = 9600;
        }
        $u = $this->user->steamid64;
        $merchant_id = '423';
        $secret_word1 = '432';
        $sign = md5($merchant_id.':'.$sum.':'.$secret_word1.':'.$u);
        $url = 'https://www.free-kassa.ru/merchant/cash.php?m='.$merchant_id.'&oa='.$sum.'&o='.$u.'&s='.$sign.'&lang=ru&i=&em=';
        $returnValue = [
            'redirect' => $url
        ];
        return $returnValue;
    }

    function getIP() {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];

        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    }

    public function payaccept(Request $request)
    {
        $merchant_id = '534';
        $secret_word2 = '423423';


        if (!in_array(getIP(), array('144.76.93.115', '144.76.93.119', '78.47.60.198'))) die('hacking attempt!');

        $sign = md5($merchant_id.':'.$_REQUEST['AMOUNT'].':'.$merchant_secret_2.':'.$_REQUEST['MERCHANT_ORDER_ID']);

        if ($sign != $_REQUEST['SIGN']) die('wrong sign');
        $summ = $_REQUEST['AMOUNT'];
        $user = User::Where('steamid64',$_REQUEST['MERCHANT_ORDER_ID']);
        if ($summ = 32) {
            $user->money += $summ;
        }elseif ($summ = 64) {
            $user->money += $summ;
        }elseif ($summ = 320) {
            $user->money += $summ;
        }elseif ($summ = 640) {
            $user->money += round($summ*1.03);
        }elseif ($summ = 1600) {
            $user->money += round($summ*1.05);
        }elseif ($summ = 3840) {
            $user->money += round($summ*1.1);
        }elseif ($summ = 6400) {
            $user->money += round($summ*1.15);
        }elseif ($summ = 9600) {
            $user->money += round($summ*2);
        }
        $user->save();


        die('YES');
    }
```

Function pay forms a link, amount and digital signature. Function payaccept the function processes the payment and must enter payment information into the database.

The problem is in line   `$user = User::Where('steamid64',$_REQUEST['MERCHANT_ORDER_ID']);` i know it with help var_dump().

This line produces a variable steamid64, but can't fint in a DB. 
How i can fix it?

Comment: Add `->first()` like `User::Where('steamid64',$_REQUEST['MERCHANT_ORDER_ID'])->first();`. You are not retrieving the record, only building a query for it.

Comment: nothing changed:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, given that you haven't put any error message or log.. I assume the error is this line:

```
$user = User::Where('steamid64',$_REQUEST['MERCHANT_ORDER_ID']);
```

Here you are creating the query... but not executing it. To do so add `->first()` at the end.

```
$user = User::Where('steamid64',$_REQUEST['MERCHANT_ORDER_ID'])->first();
```

Then you will be able to call methods on the `$user` object.

Comment: add it, nothing changed :<

Comment: @Artem try to include error messages or the php stack trace in your log file. If you don't provide further info it will very difficult for us to help you. Check this guide: [ask]

Comment: woops, check logs and problem was in Undefined variable: merchant_secret_2

Comment: @Artem glad you found a solution :+1